# Log error using serilog when host. crashes .net 6 top level statements program.cs

Tags: serilog

We are using serilog in .net 6 console application. Below code is sample program.cs. When host crashes how do we capture the exception in the configured logger?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration))
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();
try
{
   await host.RunAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Need to log the error
   // 
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the logs ?

You can try this

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        config.AddSerilog(new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration).CreateLogger());
                    })
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
            });
}
```